# Unable to login via StackExchange

Tags: bug, status-completed

At the moment, I am unable to login via StackExchange.
When I click the "Login with StackExchange" button on the login page I see three moving dots ([image]) but even after some minutes nothing happenes.
This happens in every browser I've tried (the latest versions of FF, Chrome, IE, Safari and Opera)

Comment: https://openid.stackexchange.com/affiliate/form says "Stack Exchange is currently offline, we'll be back shortly!"

Comment: There was some [scheduled maintenance](http://blog.serverfault.com/2012/10/11/working-towards-failure-testing-this-weekend/) going on earlier, servers might still be a bit cranky (or it might not just be over yet).

Comment: We are looking into this, thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was an error with our OpenID provider trying to hit a shared redis instance that moved across the country (more accurately, it was firewalled for slaving until we upgrade to 2.6 later this month)

We've moved it to a secondary instance that isn't involved in slaving and it's back online now.

Comment: Didn't what to post the same question, but i have the same problem. I'm unable to login to stackoverflow using Firefox 17. The dots appear and then nothing. In Chrome the login process is working fine. Oh and i'm using Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: @VladBalmos - please post a new question with as many details as possible - that's definitely a separate issue and hopefully we can help you out.  Also be sure to check addons and such in Firefox.